# How do you open more than one window at a time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do you open more than one window at a time in Javascript? 20 minutes of reading SO answers makes me think that

```
window.open('http://www.google.com');
alert('this does not happen');
window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');
```

should open both windows, but only google.com is opened, and the alert does not happen. How do I do this very simple thing?

(In case anyone is wondering, this is an application for my personal use, not intended to popup spam end users.)

Comment: please provide a small jsfiddle

Comment: Works for me in Firefox.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Have you disabled any add-ons or extensions?

Comment: are you opening from an user-action-derived event?

Comment: works in chrome

Comment: @dandavis Yes - I gather that has something to do with the situation?

Comment: Maybe you have a pop-up blocker, or your browser's built-in pop-up blocking is kicking in. This is exactly the sort of thing those features are designed to prevent because it's *extremely annoying* to your end users.

Comment: Works in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/x5azwcnh/1/). The strange thing is that Yahoo opens without waiting for me to respond to the alert.

Comment: @Barmar Hm... For me I get the alert, but neither window opens. Sigh, guess this is just whatever Chrome settings I have (and this question is as stupid as I was afraid it was).

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console to see if it says why it's not opening the windows?

Comment: I didn't see any error messages, no. @tadaman per the original post, the only end user involved is myself.

Comment: (To those who suggested that this was due to my popup settings, you were right. I'm going to accept the given answer and spare anyone else from spending time on it. Thank you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to specify the difference between the first and second window:

```
var a1 = window.open('http://www.google.com','1');
var a2 = window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','2');
```

Comment: (I'm accepting this answer because it's probably as helpful as could be expected, although the actual answer was, per my comment, my popup blocking settings.)